# Dynamic Vaadin chart

Tags: highcharts, vaadin

Is there a way to modify a Vaadin chart by moving a bar or a point from the chart itself? i.e. I have a bar chart with a certain value in one of the bars, I want to get a new value by dragging that bar to that new value.

There is something similar in [this](http://demo.vaadin.com/charts/?__hssc=77033354.3.1478117684533&__hstc=77033354.0fb33d69e039219115ec9d6decc9fdfb.1470767427151.1476573634447.1478117684533.7&__hsfp=2532264813&hsCtaTracking=a2f8d7da-0d95-4e11-a34d-15621001f7ae%7C2f1cf7fe-69fb-4990-8a2f-e2a94503c311#ClickToAddPoint) example, that is why I wonder if it is possible to extend this option to something like what I need.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that vaadin uses Highcharts if this is the case, maybe you can use plugins, if so I recommend:

http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/3/Draggable%20Points

Source code in case you had to rewrite it:

https://rawgit.com/highslide-software/draggable-points/master/draggable-points.js

Regards.